# Embedded keycloak application throws FreeMarkerException while files for customized themes are existing

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, customization, freemarker

The goal is to customize the login of an embedded keycloak application. It worked seamlessly for the standalone version, but the embedded version makes some small troubles

Setup

```
<keycloak.version>17.0.1</keycloak.version>
<spring.version>2.6.7</spring.version>
```

I followed the tutorials on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-keycloak-custom-themes and https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/. The files are under "themes/<myTheme>/..." and the reference to this path is set accordingly e.g. over System.property(...,...) . However, when the application runs and the theme is invoked a FreeMarkerException is thrown with the hint that it's not existing.

The exception is thrown by FreeMarkerUtil.

Answer (score 0):

The mainpoint is, that the reference was not taken by embedded keycloak. I don't know exactly why. Researching the path by the DefaultThemeManager indicates that it's searching for the path **theme/<myTheme>/...** As you might (not) noticed, the "s" is missing. So it can't find the file.[image]

In case you get a similar error, you can check the file reference.